# Problem with images on a slideshow of product displays (Views Slide, Flexslider)

Tags: commerce, views, javascript

Kind of a strange problem with trying to make a slide show of my product displays. I am creating a slideshow from content of type product display (ordered by newest first). The issue I have is that adding the fields Content: Image, Content: Product Image, or Field: Product Image doesn't load an image. I get asked about image styling, so clearly drupal knows that it's an image. I wouldn't think that I would need to add a relationship, because I have almost an identical view elsewhere that readily brings in the images. So can someone set me straight here?

Comment: Are you checking as an admin user or anonymous user ?

Comment: Admin user, shouldn't really affect this. This is in the views UI, so the admin/anonymous distinction doesn't play into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a relationship to "Content: Referenced Product" and this solved the issue.  For anyone who is new to Drupal, it isn't obvious that this is (field SKU), but this is how to link back to the content in the Product Nodes in commerce.